# how to remove duplicate characters of string column mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

and it has string column `'SELL'` it has string values like

```
2,3,2,3,5,2,5,4,,3,,3,,2,3,5,4,,5,0,2,3,,,,,,,,2,3...
```

i want to make that column like

```
2,3,5,4
```

to **remove the duplicate values** , **unwanted comma's** and **remove 0's**

is it possible to do it with mysql , please help , thanks in advance

```
UPDATE
```

i am able to remove comma's by

```
REPLACE(SELL, ',', '')
```

Comment: What sql query are you currently using? Do you mean that  `2,3,2,3,5,2,5,4,,3,,3,,2,3,5,4,,5,0,2,3,,,,,,,,2,3...` is the string value of a single rows SELL column?

Comment: @Jeemusu , still trying to write .i have no idea . i searched a lot , but did not find any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is not suited for SQL only. You should write some script (PHP, Python, Perl, etc...) to scan through your data, scrub it to meet your requirements and write it back to your table.

Comment: Yeah, you would want to get the entire string using SQL, and then use php to clean the data. Or ideally, clean it before it even goes into the database.

Comment: You might be able to, but it will be extremely difficult. SQL servers are good and should be used to store structured data. However, it is fundamentally wrong to use them to manipulate your data is some strange ways.

Comment: hi i am able to remove the comma's by REPLACE(Sell, ',', '') . is their any way to remove duplicate values

Comment: You might be able to find some shortcuts like this, but this is still NOT way to go. You're better off learning how to edit data in PHP using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Please see my answer below. There is no need for external scripts and it doesn't even require complicated query.

Comment: Simply because you can do it in MySQL does NOT mean that you should. In MVC (model/view/controller) design, database is good for Model part. You are forcing it to perform controller part (scrubbing your data), but this is conceptually wrong - bad data should never be inserted into database in first place. Also, it is not scalable - if you put too much tasks onto poor database server, it will crumble much earlier than otherwise. Database is good to store data and retrieve it - and it is better to leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible if you try. You just have to generate all numbers that exist in the string (which is out of scope of this question so I'm just gonna use a hardcoded donor table).

```
SELECT t.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(d.num
                    ORDER BY find_in_set(d.num,t.sell))
FROM table1 AS t
JOIN donor AS d ON find_in_set(d.num,t.sell)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c23/2

Comment: This solution requires to know range of used numbers upfront and populate service table with those numbers. If that range is not known, it will fail. In other words, you will be back to square one - **you will have to write a script** to handle this situation.